# Cant print a hash on a perl module

Tags: perl, hash, module, package

I have a .pm Package Test file which contains:

```
sub new{
my $hash = shift;
my $self = {};
bless($self,$class);
$self->{hash} = %hash;
return $self;}
```

and

```
sub printer{
my $self = shift;
print("Test: ",$self->{hash},"\n");
return;}
```

On my main.pl I use:

```
$test = Test->new(%myhash);
```

I don't know if explained it properly but the problem is that I can't print my hash using my printer function.
I really appreciatte some help about it and if more information about it is needed I can paste all the files here.

Comment: What is $class? $hash and %hash are different variables. `test =` is probably wrong, if `test` is a variable, it should start with a `$`.

Comment: $class is my Test, which is the package name. About the test variable I fixed that, was a type mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `->new` is the class name. The arguments to the constructor come next. Not hardwiring the class name also makes inheritance possible.

Do you understand the difference between a hash and a hash reference? `%hash` is a hash, `\%hash` is a hash reference. If `$test->{hash}` contains a hash reference, you can dereference it (i.e. retrieve the hash from it) with `%{ $test->{hash} }`. Hash values must be scalars, which means you can't make a hash a value of a hash - but you can make a hash reference the value.

I'd also recommend to indent the code properly.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{
    package Test;

    sub new {
        my ($class, %hash) = @_;
        bless { hash => \%hash }, $class;
    }

    sub printer {
        my $self = shift;
        print "Test: ", %{ $self->{hash} }, "\n";
    }
}


my %hash = ( a => 11, b => 12 );
my $t = 'Test'->new(%hash);
$t->printer;  # a11b12 or b12a11
```